# CodeIgniter and MongoDB : query

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb

I'm trying to query in MongoDB using PHP/CodeIgniter but I can't find a solution...

I have a first query in "function1" where there is

```
$this->mongo_db->where("category" => getCatID("games");
```

And in my second function "getCatID" I have

```
return $this->mongo_db->select('_id')->where("name" => $name)->get('Category');
```

But it seems that the second function continue on the first query of function1.

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/tree/v2)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your first code snippet was intended to be:

```
$this->mongo_db->where("category", getCatID("games"));
// or…
$this->mongo_db->where(array("category" => getCatID("games")));
```

I've not used this library, but from perusing the source code, it looks like all query criteria set by `where()` is accumulated in an internal `$wheres` property on the `Mongo_db` class. This only gets cleared by the private [`_clear()`](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/blob/v2/libraries/Mongo_db.php#L1895) method, which is called from the following public methods:

- [`get()`](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/blob/v2/libraries/Mongo_db.php#L1895)
- [`count()`](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/blob/v2/libraries/Mongo_db.php#L964)
- [`update()`](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/blob/v2/libraries/Mongo_db.php#L1105)
- [`update_all()`](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/blob/v2/libraries/Mongo_db.php#L1153)
- [`delete()`](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/blob/v2/libraries/Mongo_db.php#L1483)
- [`delete_all()`](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/blob/v2/libraries/Mongo_db.php#L1522)
- [`add_index()`](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/blob/v2/libraries/Mongo_db.php#L1602)
- [`remove_index()`](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/blob/v2/libraries/Mongo_db.php#L1641)
- [`remove_all_indexes()`](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/blob/v2/libraries/Mongo_db.php#L1671)

Any time either of those terminating methods are called, `$wheres` will be reset. Likewise, if those methods aren't called, older criteria may bleed into your next criteria. In your case `getCatID()` may be clearing out earlier criteria. PHP is going to execute `getCatID()` before invoking the `where()` method in which it's an argument, so I'd expect that outer `where()` call to see an empty `$wheres` array.

One solution would be to call `getCatID()` on its own before building your second query. Alternatively, you could [clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) the `Mongo_db` instance to ensure that each query is built independently.

Comment: Thanks. It is what I did. I create a another MongoDb object and I run this independently...